# Typescript. Require property 2 if property 1 is passed

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have interface like:

```
interface IProps {
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  withCounter?: boolean;
  maxCounter?: number;
}
```

How to tell typescript that if someone pass **withCounter** needs also pass **maxCounter** to my React component.

Example what I want to achieve:

```
<CustomComponent label="example" /> // OK

<CustomComponent label="example" withCounter={true} /> // ERROR no property maxCounter

<CustomComponent label="example" withCounter={true} maxCounter={100}/> // OK

<CustomComponent label="example" maxCounter={100}/> // ERROR no property withCounter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a discriminated union type in an intersection with the common properties of the component:

```
type IProps = {
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
} & ({
  withCounter?: false;
  maxCounter?: undefined;
} | {
  withCounter: true;
  maxCounter: number;
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCmATzCTgEkAFHMAZzgF44BvCuOABsUAIySCA-AC44bGFGAA7AOYBufnDDC0SABYRBAEyRRps+UrUUAvnABkcABR9yAgO7AYugMIQAroowJmaYKIJsSOqucCAoAB6+AUGmMgHGmEpIhlG2AD68Gh5eiYEmMvJ+kRqxCf6lUDKKfiBiUDkAlBQUmAEYwBCKcN5+cri+4ANIgY5gMsysbO0F0UQwflCDADyGwABuAHybAPQ7BzZd5IJI8BBcTkuc+3Cbw6Mg45CKU-DCYoKcACIkHEUOArgC4EcnkcjnAAPIAaQuV3gJigd0cDyeLxGMDGuE+3yEonEgOBoK0SAhRR8dWSnB4FSQtihkNhAFEEAg4Qg4IpbmBWCYaDF4iVksjrnAIABGDFY56vPHvAmTQLEv5kkFgqlwGnikwMpm2GoGqAMmUABktLOhsMRktRUCgACZ5VxsUr8RMvurfqSgdrKRDTXTDTwrTbIXa4Jzubz+ZohbBqHrPLSkiYgA)